# Sonar doesn't follow or supply space option from checkstyle

Tags: checkstyle, sonarqube

I am using Sonar to present state of our code. We have a checkstyle xml document with our rule. In it, we have the "Method param pad" rule:

```
<module name="MethodParamPad">
    <property name="tokens" value="METHOD_DEF"/>
    <property name="option" value="space"/>
    <property name="allowLineBreaks" value="true"/> 
</module>
```

However, the result in sonar is filled with violations against this rule, concerning spaces between the method name and the first parentheses, which I feel should be allowed with the "option".

In the Sonar UI, there is no way of entering a value for the option, doesn't Sonar support it?

Answer (score 0):

Sonar uses the maven checkstyle plugin to perform the analysis.  The latest version of the plugin (2.5) uses checkstyle 5.0, but the *documentation* for the 'option' property wasn't added until checkstyle 5.1.  This could be why it was missed in the Sonar rules.

Looks like [you posted a JIRA issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ViewIssue.jspa?key=SONAR-1721) that has been fixed, so this problem should go away in 2.3.  (It would be nice if it were possible to update the standard plugins independently, but I don't see them listed anywhere)